# How to conditionally validate a form field in a react hook form

Tags: forms, next.js, react-hook-form, zod

In my Next.js project, I have a form (created using React Hook Form) that looks like this:

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
"use client";

import * as z from "zod";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { Icons } from "@/components/icons";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Switch } from "@/components/ui/switch";
import { Textarea } from "@/components/ui/textarea";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";
import { ChartFormSchema } from "@/components/validations";

export type ChartFormDataType = z.infer<typeof ChartFormSchema>;

export function ExplainChartForm() {
  const [isUploading, setIsUploading] = useState(false);
  const [selectedFileName, setSelectedFileName] = useState("No file chosen");

  const {
    reset,
    watch,
    control,
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<ChartFormDataType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(ChartFormSchema),
  });

  const addContextValue = watch("addContext");

  async function onUploadChart(formData: ChartFormDataType) {
    console.log(formData);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onUploadChart)}>
        <div className="space-y-6">
          <div className="grid gap-2">
            <div className="w-full h-60 border-2 rounded-md bg-zinc-50 flex items-center justify-center border-dashed relative">
              <input
                id="chart"
                type="file"
                accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg"
                disabled={isUploading}
                className="visually-hidden"
                {...register("chart", {
                  onChange: (event) => {
                    setSelectedFileName(event.target.files[0].name);
                  },
                })}
              />
              <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 items-center">
                <label
                  htmlFor="chart"
                  className="w-auto shadow flex justify-center items-center bg-white px-2 py-1 rounded-md border text-zinc-700 hover:bg-blue-100 hover:border-blue-200 hover:text-blue-800 active:bg-blue-800 active:border-blue-800 active:text-white transition-colors"
                >
                  <Icons.fileImage className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
                  Select file
                </label>
                <p className="text-sm text-zinc-500">{selectedFileName}</p>
                {selectedFileName === "No file chosen" && (
                  <p className="text-xs text-zinc-500 absolute left-0 right-0 bottom-[10px] text-center">
                    Acceptable formats: PNG, JPG, JPEG. Maximum file size: 10MB.
                  </p>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
            {errors.chart && (
              <p className="px-1 text-sm text-red-600 animate-in fade-in-0 slide-in-from-left-1">
                {errors.chart.message as string}
              </p>
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col space-y-6">
            <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
              <Label htmlFor="addContext">Add context</Label>
              <Controller
                name="addContext"
                control={control}
                render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                  <Switch
                    id="addContext"
                    checked={value}
                    onCheckedChange={onChange}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </div>
            {addContextValue && (
              <div>
                <Textarea
                  placeholder="Type chart details here."
                  {...register("context")}
                />
                <p className="text-sm text-muted-foreground px-1">
                  Provide details about the chart to help our AI analyze and
                  explain it more effectively.
                </p>
                {addContextValue && errors.context && (
                  <p className="px-1 text-sm text-red-600 animate-in fade-in-0 slide-in-from-left-1">
                    {errors.context.message as string}
                  </p>
                )}
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
          <Button
            disabled={isUploading}
            type="submit"
            className="w-full bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 rounded-md text-base"
          >
            {isUploading ? (
              <>
                <Icons.spinner className="mr-2 h-4 w-4 animate-spin" />
                Explaining...
              </>
            ) : (
              "Explain"
            )}
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Note that I am using `shadcn/ui` for form components.

Here is my form schema:

```
import * as z from "zod";

const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 10000000; // 10 MB
const ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES = ["image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"];

export const ChartFormSchema = z.object({
  chart: z
    .any()
    .refine((fileList) => fileList?.length > 0, {
      message: "Image file is missing.",
    })
    .refine((fileList) => fileList?.[0]?.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE, {
      message: "Max file size is 10MB.",
    })
    .refine((fileList) => ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES.includes(fileList?.[0]?.type), {
      message: "Only png, jpg and jpeg files are accepted.",
    }),
  addContext: z.boolean(),
  context: z
    .string()
    .optional()
    .refine(
      (text) => {
        return text !== undefined && text?.trim().length > 0;
      },
      {
        message: "Chart details are missing",
      }
    )
    .refine(
      (text = "") => {
        // Split the text into words and count them
        const wordCount = text
          .trim()
          .split(/\s+/)
          .filter((word) => word.length > 0).length;
        return wordCount <= 100;
      },
      {
        message: "Chart details should not exceed 100 words.",
      }
    ),
});
```

Currently, if I don't upload a file and `Add context` toggle switch is off, and I click on the `Explain` button, I get form validation error for the `chart` field, as shown below:

[image]

If I toggle on the `Add context` switch, I see the form validation error message for the `context` field as well, as shown below:

[image]

But **I don't want the textarea field validation to happen when the value of `addContext` is `false`. How can I enforce this requirement?**

Comment: Your descriptions about what is actually happening and what you want to happen are a little unclear. 

Is the textfield validation happening even when the `addContext` toggle is off?

Comment: @DerekGlassick Yes. And I want the textfield validation to happen only when the `addContext` toggle is on.

Comment: I think what you can do is add this: `{ required: addContextValue}` to your `context` `register()` to maybe get this working. I'm not sure if that will override what you are supplying through your `ChartSchema` if it doesn't then you may need to construct your form schema in a way where you can pass it `addContextValue`. You can check the `register()` validation options [here](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Applyvalidation).